# Login trying to pass variables to landing page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I changed my login page to use PDO.  After researching, I can't seem to find a solution on how to pass variables that are not defined in the login page.  I can pass the username and display it with no issues but the memberid and firstname doesn't pass no matter what I try.

1. I'm trying to pass id and firstname -  to display the first name.  The id is to define who's logged in because data will be populating a database with existing info for that user.
2. There are two databases, one with registration info - id, firstname, lastname, password.....
   The second database will populate examination info and will be linked with the registration database < again so it knows who's taking the exam.

Here's the code I've tried to pass the variables needed to landing page minus html.

**LOGIN.php**

```
    require_once('inc/config.php');

    //check if already logged in move to home page
    if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: members.php'); } 

    //process login form if submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $memberID = $_POST['memberID'];
        $firstname= $_POST['firstname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($user->login($email,$password)){ 
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $memberID;
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
            header('Location: members.php');
            exit;

        } else {
            $error[] = 'Wrong email or password.';
        }

    }

   ?>
```

**USER.php** This is where I've added memberid and firstname but not passing.

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){  

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT memberID, firstname, password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes WHERE memberID = :memberID AND firstname = :firstname LIMIT 1" ');


            $stmt->execute(array('memberID' => $memberID));
            $stmt->execute(array('firstname' => $firstname));
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }       
    }

}


?>
```

**LANDING PAGE**  Here's what I have at the top of the landing page.

```
<?php
session_start();
 $_SESSION['memberID'] = $memberID['memberID'];
 $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname['firstname'];
?>
```

**And this in the html**

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['memberID']; ?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>
```

If someone could help that would be great.  Please understand I read PDO is better for logins and this is the reason I'm changing over to PDO.  I'm not a  genius and I'm here for help.

**UPDATE**

After more testing it doesn't know what memberid is, it's undefined.  Can someone tell me how to define and grab it from the db in user.php?   This will solve the problem.  I can't figure out how to do it with the code that's already there.

Answer (score -1):

Fist thing I see is you aren't passing them into `get_user_hash` that means they don't exists inside that functions [scope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)), even if they have the same name

Comment: Thanks b729sefc.  Do you mean like this -  private function get_user_hash($username, $memberID, $firstname) ?  When I do that I get - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.   Then I added -  $stmt->execute(array('memberID' => $memberID)); $stmt->execute(array('firstname' => $firstname));  but I get the same message - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.

Comment: You also need to pass them through in the login function as well

Comment: Correct and I've done that -  if($user->login($email,$password,$memberID,$firstname)){ 
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  $_SESSION['memberID'] = $memberID;
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;

Comment: Anyone else have any idea why the variables are not passing?   If you guys don't know, putting mysqli back in.